# How can I get the Server Side ID of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I need to do a `__doPostBack` in a WebForms of this LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AggiungiSocial" runat="server" onclick="cmdAggregaSocial_Click">Link</asp:LinkButton>
```

I see that .NET process it as:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Dashboard1$RepeaterSocials$ctl00$AggiungiSocial','')
```

so what I need is `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Dashboard1$RepeaterSocials$ctl00$AggiungiSocial','')`.

But rendered, the ID is instead `ContentPlaceHolder1_Dashboard1_RepeaterSocials_AggiungiSocial_0`

So Do I need to do a javascript replace/parse of that ID or is there a method to get this "__dopostback" UserControl id?

Such as:

```
var ServerIDUserControl = link.attr('href').replace("javascript:__doPostBack(", "").replace("','')", "");
```

(which is terrible imo).

Comment: i usually call __doPostBack function from the code behind

Comment: what you need is UniqueID. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Perhaps depending on which (ASP).NET version you're using) the `name` attribute value will contain the string you're looking for, as opposed to the `id` being made identifier-friendly. An example from a 3.5 site here at work looks like this for a `Button`:

```
<input type="submit" 
  name="ctl00$cph_main$ctl00$PerformSearch"
  id="ctl00_cph_main_ctl00_PerformSearch">
```

I parenthesise the first part simply because I have to admit my ignorance as to when/why this happened - I recall a time when this wasn't the case, and it could be either a 3.5+ thing or a configured thing.

Otherwise you could use the inline server-side script syntax to output the `control.UniqueID` in the appropriate place.

Comment: I'm on .NET 4, I don't see any name attribute?

Comment: You could then maybe use the `ClientID` property, see my update.

Comment: ClientID is different than Name. I need to call dopostback remember? I think you mean UniqueID?

Comment: @markzzz Ah, yes. Not had to do this kind of hack for a _lonnng_ time. UniqueID could be your friend.

Comment: @markzzz I found a post by Scott Guthrie showing [how to supposedly re-enable this behaviour in .NET 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To get the id of the control sent as `__EVENTTARGET` during postback you need to use the `UniqueID` property of `Control`. In your case:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('<%= AggiungiSocial.UniqueID %>', '');
```

However, from your example I see that your control is nested inside a repeater called `RepeaterSocials`. In this case, your code might look like this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('<%= RepeaterSocials.Items[0].FindControl("AggiungiSocial").UniqueID %>', '');
```

But my advice is to not use this approach. You can instead capture the [Repeater.ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event and see which button was clicked inside the repeater.

Comment: this has been flagged in the lqp queue.  Can you please explain what this answer does to solve the OP's question?  Or otherwise add substance that can endure as an answer?

Comment: @GarryVass the question was "I need to do a __doPostBack in a WebForms of this LinkButton:" so i provided the code for him. Anyway, i modified my answer and added a little substance.